# Correct way to source .bashrc for non-interactive shell

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, openmpi

I have been trying to resolve problems to be able to run openmpi on multiple nodes.

Initially I had a problem with `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables not being updated from `.bashrc` file by openmpi session, so I manually added `--prefix /path/to/openmpi` to resolve this issue.

Turns out that even the anaconda path variables are not being loaded as well. So ultimately I need `~/.bashrc` file to be sourced from my home directory. How can I do that? Can anyone help me out please?

**UPDATE 01:**

I wrote a simple shell script to check the version of python

```
python --version
```

and tried to run it with openmpi on local as well as remote machine as follows:

```
mpirun --prefix /home/usama/.openmpi --hostfile hosts -np 4 bash script
```

And it returns

```
Python 2.7.12
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
Python 2.7.12
```

Confirming my suspicion that whatever openmpi is doing to run remote processes doesn't invoke / set proper environment variables from the ~/.bashrc file. Any help from someone who has worked with multi-node openmpi?

**UPDATE 02:**

A simple ssh environment grep tell me that my environment variables are not updated which might be the cause of the problem. (I have even tried to set it up in ~/.ssh/environment file)

```
$ ssh remote-node env | grep -i path
```

It seems to be loading only the /etc/environment file with only basic paths setup. How to I rectify this?

Comment: How exactly are you attempting to run something? Are you sure Bash is being invoked?

Comment: Well the openmpi FAQ says that an ssh connection is made to remote servers to start new process. I am assuming this involves bash? The error I am getting is about python libraries not being installed on remote machine when they are installed using conda and environment variables are set in .bashrc

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to indicate exactly how you run things. Noninteractive SSH will read `$HOME/.ssh/environment` on the destination but we really need to see the full picture before making specific recommendations.

Comment: Well you wait too. Are you looking for a modular solution which solves the problem for Bash in general (which "correct way" in the question title implies to me) or a specific hack to work around the problem when using SSH login (which `.ssh/environment` provides), or perhaps only when using noninteractive SSH login under OpenMPI?

Comment: @tripleee I have updated the answer to what I am doing. And a general solution would be great but if a hack can get openmpi to work then I am all for it.

Comment: and oh adding environment variables etc to .ssh/environment doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @tripleee the problem seems to be with the ssh as when I use `ssh remote_node env | grep -i path` I don't see my variable updates. Any suggestions please?

Comment: `bash --rcfile` is definitely a workaround. The `.ssh/environment` hack might be disabled server-side; maybe also check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to verify.

Comment: I would call "don't" the only appropriate answer. Users generally maintain `.bashrc` assuming that it impacts only their interactive shells, and thus that they can define functions that override builtin commands at will, set unusual `DEBUG` traps or `command_not_found` hooks, and otherwise do things that can make scripts behave unpredictably.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So technically no way to solve this issue? I ended up adding my required paths in the /etc/environment file for the time being but this isn't safe or recommended is it?

Comment: I didn't say there was no way, I said the way you're asking for is ill-advised. Better to use a separate dotfile rather than sharing one also used for interactive configuration, or -- better -- generating commands that explicitly set the values they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should run like this.I guess.
two ways help you!

first:

```
mpirun --prefix /home/usama/.openmpi --hostfile hosts -np 4 . ~/.bashrc && bash script
```

second:

```
## 1. add this line to the script
. ~/.bashrc

## 2. run command as you do
mpirun --prefix /home/usama/.openmpi --hostfile hosts -np 4 bash script
```